# How to restrict Google Drive API access to one folder

Tags: google-api

My app uses the Dropbox API which by default limits my app to its own folder located in the user's Dropbox "Apps" folder.

In contrast, when my app uses the Google Drive API it has access to the entire contents of the user's drive.

Is there a way to configure the Google Drive API to allow my app access only to a particular folder? (similar to the Dropbox approach)

Added info: the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata approach creates a hidden folder used by the app. In my case the user needs to see and access the files uploaded and downloaded by the app.

Comment: In your situation, how about using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`? The official document of this scope is `Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) I thought that this might be able to be used for achieving your goal. But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your goal. So I posted it as a comment. I apologize for this.